# IE9 Shrinking DIV on overflow:auto scrollbar appearance

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm having a little bit of trouble getting everything to work right on my website with internet explorer. One of my problems is, I have a div that has `overflow:auto`.

Once I make my window small enough for the overflow to take affect, the div shrinks a tad bit for some reason. Does anyone know why this would be?

**The Page `width:100%`** - Note the red border on the left and right.
[image]

**The Page once `overflow:auto` takes affect** - Red bordered div shrinks
[image]

**The Red Bordered Div**

```
.content {
   width:100%;
   background-color:#F1F2F7;
   position: absolute;
   padding:0 0 120px 0;
   z-index:2;
   overflow:auto;
   height:100%;
   border:1px solid red;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't it shrinks in other browsers too? Try overflow:y-scroll; To make it show in all browsers.

Comment: @Medda86 It doesn't shrink in other browsers. The reason it is on auto is because IE shows the scrollbars no matter what with `overflow:scroll`. I will try y-scroll when I get to a windows computer tomorrow and we will see what happens

Comment: I chekced, is called overflow-y:scroll; ... yeah I'm not sure.. let me know how it plays out :)

Comment: Are you using border box as your box sizing style on the element with the scrollbar? I just had this issue, and mine was solved by making sure I set the div with the scroll to content box.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem to this.  The scroll bar was correctly positioned in IE10+, FF and Chrome, but inset like your screenshot in IE9. This was the fix:

```
    .dgrid-scroller {
        box-sizing: content-box;
    }
```

Our project, like many, normalized all elements to box-sizing:border-box and that appears to cause problems for the dGrid measurement code in IE9.

Comment: Perfect answer. I was looking for this solution for a long time. You are a life saver. I have having issue with ignite igCombo in IE9 and this solution fixed it. Thanks a lot. I wish I could up-vote your answer more than once.

Comment: This will become more problematic if you have some horizontal padding applied. I've seen that replacing `width: 100%` with `right: 0` works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

It is due to "BORDER", remove border and keep everything else as it is.
It will work.

```
.content {
   width:100%;
   background-color:#F1F2F7;
   position: absolute;
   padding:0 0 120px 0;
   z-index:2;
   overflow:auto;
   height:100%;
}
```

Comment: It is not due to the border.

Comment: Can I have JSFiddle code for this, so that I can have more clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, Working fine in IE8/IE9.

Updated few properties in CSS:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>IE 9 Scrollbar</title>
<style>
body { margin:0; padding:0; overflow-y:scroll;}
.content {
   width:100%;
   background-color:#F1F2F7;
   position: absolute;
   padding:0 0 120px 0;
   z-index:2;
   overflow:auto;
   height:100%;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="content">
        test
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the div shrinking was because of `position:absolute`. Removing this solved the problem in IE 9.